# Rally Ad-in for Excel- I can not connect to rally

Tags: plugins, rally

I cannot connect to rally after installation of excel plugin. After every attempt of connection I receive message listed below:

> Error connecting to Rally: Unable to connect to the remote server
>   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest&
>   request)    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)    at
>   Rally.RestApi.HttpService.Get(Uri target, IDictionary`2 headers)    at
>   Rally.RestApi.RallyRestApi.MakeRequest(Uri uri)    at
>   Rally.RestApi.RallyRestApi.GetByReference(String aRef, String[]
>   fetchedFields)    at
>   Rally.RestApi.RallyRestApi.GetCurrentUser(String[] fetchedFields)
>   at RallyExcel.ExcelRestApi.GetUserInfo(Boolean includeWorkspaceData)
>   in E:\projects\exceladdin_tmp\RallyExcel\ExcelRestApi.cs:line 48    at
>   RallyExcel.RallyConnectionDialog.OnOKClicked(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) in
>   E:\projects\exceladdin_tmp\RallyExcel\RallyConnectionDialog.cs:line 65

I have reinstalled plugin several times with no results. I also download .msi installation file from Rally page few times for those installations (in case it was broken).

I do not think that it is related with the Internet network since I was trying to connect using several different LANs with no results.

Looking at error message it seems that plugin need some files from disk “E:\”, which is (in my case) CD/DVD drive.  I can not find any place (e.g. configuration file) where I can change this setting and direct it to any existing disk.

Finally, this problem appears also for my colleagues. We all are using Lenovo ThinkPad with Win 7 (usually 64) and MS Office 2010.

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Does your subscription use SSO authentication? Or perhaps a proxy?

Comment: Also, have you double checked to make sure you have both Microsoft .NET Framework 4 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime installed?

If you do not you can download those from the Rally Excel Installation and User Guide page here: https://prod.help.rallydev.com/rally-add-excel-installation-user-guide#Installation

Answer (score 1):

I received the error below while trying to connect to Rally via Excel. It was because I needed to change my password in Rally.  Once I opened up Rally in my browser and logged in, the web site requested that I change my password.  Once I did that, I was able to connect to Rally via Excel.

```
Error connecting to Rally: Invalid JSON primitive: .
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
   at Rally.RestApi.DynamicJsonSerializer.Deserialize(String json)
   at Rally.RestApi.RallyRestApi.GetByReference(String aRef, String[] fetchedFields)
   at RallyExcel.RallyRestApiWrapper.GetCurrentUser(String[] fetchedFields) in C:\Users\admin\Documents\exceladdin\RallyExcel\ExcelRestApi.cs:line 343
   at RallyExcel.ExcelRestApi.GetUserInfo(Boolean includeWorkspaceData) in C:\Users\admin\Documents\exceladdin\RallyExcel\ExcelRestApi.cs:line 78
   at RallyExcel.RallyConnectionDialog.OnConnectClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\admin\Documents\exceladdin\RallyExcel\RallyConnectionDialog.cs:line 168
```